# Removing items from an array in mongo document, but not sure if the key has an array or is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm writing code to remove elements from an array using `$pull`, but sometimes the key is set to an array and sometimes the key is set to null.  The `updateMany` call/pull operation blows up when it encounters a document whose key is set to null.

Is there a way to tell mongo to skip a document if the key happens to be null?  This wouldn't be a problem if the documents in the collection had keys populated with an empty array instead of null, but that's not the case.

```
let operation = {
    $pull: { Key1: { $in: arrayOfStrings },
             Key2: { $in: arrayOfStrings } }
};
db.collection("collection").updateMany({ }, operation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often happens, I wound up with the solution to this as I was writing the question.  The answer is to add filter for the key not being null.  That requires two updates/filters.

```
let filter1 = { Key1: { $ne: null } };
let filter2 = { Key2: { $ne: null } };

let operation1 = { $pull: { Key1: { $in: arrayOfStrings } } };
let operation2 = { $pull: { Key2: { $in: arrayOfStrings } } };

db.collection("collection").updateMany(filter1, operation1);
db.collection("collection").updateMany(filter2, operation2);
```

Hope this helps someone else!  And feel free to post a comment or another answer if you know of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation uses [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) stage to process the `Key1` and `Key2` separately, but with one pass only. The processsed documents are updated in the following `forEach` cursor method (note the aggregation returns a *cursor* with transformed documents).

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $facet: {
          key1_match: [
              { 
                  $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$Key1", null ] }, { $isArray: "$Key1" } ] } }
              },
              {
                  $project: { Key1: { $setDifference: [ "$Key1", INPUT_ARRAY ] } }
              }
          ],
          key2_match: [
              { 
                  $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$Key2", null ] }, { $isArray: "$Key2" } ] } } 
              },
              {
                  $project: { Key2: { $setDifference: [ "$Key2", INPUT_ARRAY ] } }
              }
          ],
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          result: { $concatArrays: [ "$key1_match", "$key2_match" ] } 
      }
  },
  {
      $unwind: "$result"
  },
  {
      $group: { 
          _id: "$result._id", 
          result: { $mergeObjects: "$result" } }
  },
  {
      $project: { 
          Key1: { $ifNull: [ "$result.Key1", null ] }, 
          Key2: { $ifNull: [ "$result.Key2", null ] }
      } 
  } 
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { Key1: doc.Key1, Key2: doc.Key2 } } ) )
```

Consider the following *input documents*:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "Key1" : null, "Key2" : [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "Key1" : [ "one", "three", "nine", "ten" ], "Key2" : null }
{ "_id" : 3, "Key1" : [ "blue", "red", "green" ], "Key2" : [ "nine", "three", "blue" ] }
```

The input *array of strings* to be removed:

```
var INPUT_ARRAY = [ "one", "three" , "blue", "xyz" ]
```

After the query is applied, the *updated documents*:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "Key1" : null, "Key2" : [ "two", "four" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "Key1" : [ "nine", "ten" ], "Key2" : null }
{ "_id" : 3, "Key1" : [ "red", "green" ], "Key2" : [ "nine" ] }
```